# Google apps script - "File xyz.csv exceeds the maximum file size."

Tags: google-apps-script

I try to parse a .csv in Google scirpts, but it says the csv would exceed the maximum file size.
The same code worked perfectly till yesterday.

This is the code:

```
var fileIterator = DriveApp.getFolderById("xxx").getFilesByName("xyz.csv");
while (fileIterator.hasNext()) {
  var csv = Utilities.parseCsv(fileIterator.next().getBlob().getDataAsString("UTF-16"), "\t");
}
```

Do you have any idea or suggestion, what the problem can be?

Thank you in advance,
Andras

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is exactly what Google is telling you -- your file is exceeding their maximum allowed file size.

Google limits file (document) uploads on Google Drive to 50MB. You can find more information in the link provided [here](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/37603?hl=en).